# Exported Azure Resource Group Template has null parameters

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

Trying to recreate a resource group from template I previously exported but getting this error :

`The value of deployment parameter 'Redis_polyrediscachegraphicsxp_name' is null. Please specify the value or use the parameter reference.`

Indeed the parameters.json file has null values :

```
 "parameters": {
    "Redis_polyrediscachegraphicsxp_name": {
        "value": null
    },
    "storageAccounts_polystorgraphicsxp_name": {
        "value": null
    },
    "databaseAccounts_polycosmosgraphicsxp_name": {
        "value": null
    }
}
```

How can this be fixed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error already shows the mistake you made. Your parameters are null. So you need to change your parameters.json file with the right values like this:

```
"parameters": {
    "Redis_polyrediscachegraphicsxp_name": {
        "value": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "storageAccounts_polystorgraphicsxp_name": {
        "value": "xxxxxx"
    },
    "databaseAccounts_polycosmosgraphicsxp_name": {
        "value": "xxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Take the example [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-simple-windows).

Comment: I understand that. But I exported the template from the Azure portal. Therefore I'd expect everything to work out of the box, but maybe I misuderstood ARM templates. Are they not supposed to represent my existing resources ?

Comment: @Sam I don't think so. The Azure Template used to make the deployment more convenient. It does not represent any existing resources.

Comment: @Sam Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it as the answer.